# Spigot Plugin Development - Subtract variable when player dies

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I would like to make plugin, that counts player's lives. For example every player has 3 lives. Whenever he dies, he lost 1 life. When he reach 0 lives, he gets banned.

My method looks like this

```
public class OnPlayerDeath implements Listener {

    private int lives = 3;

    @EventHandler
    public void OnDeath(PlayerDeathEvent event){
        Player player = event.getEntity().getPlayer();
        if (!(player.getKiller() instanceof Player)) 
            player.sendMessage("Died by a something else. You have " + lives + " lives left.");
        else {
            player.sendMessage("Died by a human. You have " + lives + " lives left.");
            lives--;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, whenever player dies, the message shows all the time same variable "3". How to fix that?

Comment: Are you creating `new OnPlayerDeath()` every time `OnDeath()` is called? you also decrease `lives` only in the `else` block, is that on purpose? In any case, I think `lives` should be part of `Player`, not in another class that probably shouldn't be a class in anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to save the amount of lives for each player.

Try using a `HashMap`

For instance:

```
public class OnPlayerDeath implements Listener {

// Make new HashMap
private Map<Player, Integer> livesMap = new HashMap<>();

@EventHandler
public void OnDeath(PlayerDeathEvent event){
    Player player = event.getEntity().getPlayer();

    int lives;

    if(!livesMap.containsKey(player)) {
        // Set the default amount of lives to 2. (3 minus 1, since the player already died once)
        lives = 2;
    } else {
        // Subtract one from the player's lives
        lives = livesMap.get(player) - 1;  
    }

    if (!(player.getKiller() instanceof Player)) {
        player.sendMessage("Died by a something else. You have " + lives + " lives left.");
    } else {
        player.sendMessage("Died by a human. You have " + lives + " lives left.");
    }

    // Update new life count
    livesMap.put(player, lives);
}
```

}

A [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) allows you to save a value for each key. In this case the life count for each player.

Comment: But if you have for example 1 life, then reconnect, you have 2 lives again. How to fix that? Maybe some config file for storage integers?

Comment: The lives of a player will remain saved until you restart or reload your server. If you want the lives to be saved, you'll have to write the data to a file when the server shuts down. (`onDisable()`) and you have to read the data when the player connects.

I suggest you look at Bukkit [FileConfiguration](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/file/FileConfiguration.html). If you need help, feel free to ask another question.